# XPath | path expression .Net

Tags: xml, xpath, expression

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Country>
  <States>
    <County>
      <popularity>39</popularity>
      <name>Orange</name>
      <id>13811</id>
      <url>http://www.url.gov</url>
      <overview>Orange County Overview</overview>
      <Cities>
        <City name="City #1" size="big" population="33333"/>
        <City name="City #2" size="medium" population="2222"/>
        <City name="City #3" size="Small" population="111"/>
      </Cities>
    </County>
  </States>
</Country>
```

What is the equivalent XPath expression of "select [cities] where [name]='Orange'" for the XML above?

**Edit 07/27/09 00:29 AM PST:**

I got it!
Thank you all for the advices, you are are great teachers.
I was able to select all attributes from all"City" with

```
/Country/States/County[name='Orange']/Cities/City
```

Comment: Could you clarify which elements you want to select and which element/attribute you want to filter on?  (do you want all of the <City> elements or all of the <Cities> elements)

Comment: I wanted to get all attributes one by one from all <City>. Thank you guys for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

`//Cities[../name="Orange"]/*`

The predicate in brackets `[../name="Orange"]` is roughly equivalent to a where clause.

Comment: /Country/States/County/Cities[../name='Orange'] would be better.  Double slashes are terribly inefficient.  With the sample document, not a big deal, but for large documents it helps to eliminate full tree scans.

Comment: "Double slashes are terribly inefficient"?! To my experience, the dependants() operator is quite efficient compared to checking the names of a whole path of XML elements. However, it depends on the index the XPath implementation uses.

Answer (score 0):

`//*[name="Orange"]/Cities/*`